# Скрипт для адаптации скрывающий и открывающий див

Tags: javascript, jquery

При адаптации сайта под мобильники выпадающее меню заваливается на div. Хотелось бы исправить это с помощью JQuery... только вот не получается написать скрипт, который бы при определенном разрешении экрана работал по типу этого:

`$(".main_mnu_button").click(function() {
    $(".inf_wrapper").slideToggle();  });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Определяем ширину экрана
var w = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width();

//Если ширина меньше 640px
if (w <= 640) {
    $(".main_mnu_button").click(function() {
        $(".inf_wrapper").slideToggle(400);  
    });
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!